# Can we authenticate tokens in an api resource from an app configured with identity server and another app configured with latest asp net identity?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a situation where i have 3 apps, an identity server , and one microservice resource and one app that has asp net identity configured, How can i configure my api resource to accept tokens from the app that has configured identity server and the other app configured with asp net identity. im currently facing an issue where if i install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt either of the tokens will not be validated and there are errors. Can someone please guide me how i can correctly accept and validate tokens from both authentication servers servers.
below is my program.cs file from the api resource, apologies if my i haven't elaborated much on this issue.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("IdentityServer")
    .AddJwtBearer("IdentityServer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:7032/";
        options.Audience = "scope1";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("AspNetIdentity").AddJwtBearer("AspNetIdentity", options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["APIKey:Secret"])),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["APIKey:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["APIKey:Audience"]
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ClientsAndUsers", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", new List<string> { "User", "Client" }));
    options.AddPolicy("ClientsOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Client"));
    options.AddPolicy("UsersOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Role", "User"));
});
```

configured my api resource to accept tokens from the app that has configured identity server and the other app configured with asp net identity.